# How to handle https clients with sockets in python? Making proxy server

Tags: python, sockets, https, proxy

Im creating proxy server using sockets in python. I know how to handle http clients. But with https it doesnt work. I send to client message that everything is ok. Then i try to wrap client socket as a secure socket. But it doesnt work.

I got message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-14:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Даниил/Downloads/python/proxy_server/proxy_server.py", line 39, in __handle_client
    self.__handle_https(client_sock, client_data, host, port)
  File "C:/Users/Даниил/Downloads/python/proxy_server/proxy_server.py", line 62, in __handle_https
    server_side=True)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1238, in wrap_socket
    suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:1076)
```

I have certificate with Common Name: localhost and i added it in browser. Even when I create certificate with Common Name of host (e.g. docs.python.org) and add it to browser it doesnt work.

Here is my code of handling https requests:

```
   def __handle_https(self, client_sock, data, host, port):
        client_sock.sendall(b'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n\r\n')

        sclient = ssl.wrap_socket(client_sock,
                                  certfile='server.crt',
                                  keyfile='server.key',
                                  server_side=True)
```

Comment: I came across https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/22625 and I wonder if your client/browser supports TLS 1.3, and your server only accepts that?

Comment: Well, i cant really understand what does it mean :( I accept http packages and then decide if it is still http or https. Also my proxy server on localhost:8080 (if this information is important).

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP proxy should only forward the data between client and server after the CONNECT request is done. It should not handle the TLS itself as you try. Instead it should forward the data unchanged so that there is an end-to-end TLS connection between the client to the server via the proxy.

Comment: You mean i have to transfer data to server, which client try to connect to?

Comment: @GilmutdninovDaniil: On `CONNECT host:port` request the proxy should connect to the given `host:port` and once this succeeded then the `HTTP/1.0 200 ...` back to the client. From then on the proxy should forward all data read from the client to the server and all data read from the server to the client. No changes should be made to the data.

Comment: I tried it. But after i send HTTP/1.0 200 to client he sends me strange message (as i understand its part of handshake, so before i start to transfer data from client to server i have to make handshake with client with my proxy). When I send data after HTTP/1.0 200 to server(host:host) it says that it is a Bad request.

Comment: @GilmutdninovDaniil: "so before i start to transfer data from client to server i have to make handshake with client with my proxy"* - this is exactly not what you should do. The proxy should forward __all__ data from the client __after__ the CONNECT request is done to the server and __all__ data from the server back to the client. The proxy should not do the TLS handshake with the client but instead forward it so that the server can do the handshake. The proxy should not send any data to the server apart from __all__ the clients data __after__ the CONNECT request.

Comment: So, Now I dont do handshake with proxy but error is the same:https://pastebin.com/BNJKRcEH

Comment: option - do_handshake_on_connect

Comment: @GilmutdninovDaniil: based on your code the proxy clearly tries to do a TLS handshake with client and server. This is wrong - the proxy should not do this and instead just forward the data. TLS handshakes to both sides should only be done if you want to do TLS interception, but in this case the client must trust the proxies certificate. `certificate unknown` refers to the problem that a certificate is not trusted by the peer, i.e. your `server.crt` is not acceptable by the client. Why this is the case is not clear but you should get an error message in your browser with more details.

Comment: Hmm... But how to generate true certificate for proxy? I tried generate certificate with Common Name of host. But it doesnt work as well. By the way i got this error in browser: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: @GilmutdninovDaniil: This means that the subject (CN, SAN) of the certificate does not match the domain name in the URL. Thus, you need to fix at least one of these. Typically SSL intercepting proxy generate certificates on the fly for the requested domain based on a trusted CA - but how to do this is way out of the context of your original question.